# How does "item.enabled = item2.enabled = item3.enabled = value" work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Feeling like **less-code-is-better-code** so wanted to "optimize" how to enable several items at the same time:

```
button1.enabled = YES;
button2.enabled = YES;
textField.enabled = YES;
```

...using this code. But **what does it actually do?** I believe button2 enabled state will be defined by result of setting textField enabled state? If textField case fails for unknown reason, then button1 would get result of operation of setting button2 enabled status?

At least in theory textField.enabled could be whatever, button2.enabled NO and button1.enabled YES ?!?!?

```
button1.enabled = button2.enabled = textField.enabled = YES;
```

What could go wrong? Is this safe at all?

Comment: Less code is _not_ better code if the code becomes in any way ambiguous, or prone to subtle bugs such as those pointed out by @Chuck in his comment below. Shorter code is not necessarily more readable - being 'clever' often reduces readability. It's usually better to avoid tricks like this unless you've got a really good reason not to. You'll thank yourself in 6 months time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that assignment is also an expression in C. Its value is the value that’s stored to the variable being assigned to. In other words, `foo = 5` assigns `5` to `foo` and the whole expression has value `5`.

This feature leads to some shortcuts similar to yours, the most famous one being probably `while (*dst++ = *src++)` to copy a null-terminated string `src` to `dst`. In Objective-C you can often see the feature in the initializers:

```
- (id) init {
    if !(self = [super init]) // self = super init; self == nil?
         return nil;
    …
    return self;
}
```

Notice the single `=`, that’s not a bug. But since it *can* be a great source of bugs (when you really meant `==`), modern compilers will often warn about the assignment and you have to enclose it in another pair of braces to silence the warning: `if ((self = [super init]))`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's safe. You will set to `YES` all properties before `=`.

If I'm not mistaken operations are performed from right to left:

1. `textField.enabled` will be equal to YES
2. `button2.enabled` will be equal to result of operation `textField.enabled = YES;` that will be `YES`
3. `button1.enabled` wil be equal to `button2.enabled = YES;` that will be equal to `YES` (from 2) )

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is subtly wrong. IIRC, dot-syntax setters merely return the assigned value, not the resultant value of the property. So, for example, if a hypothetical `-[Person setPhoneNumber:]` method formatted the phone number American style, `textField.stringValue = person.phoneNumber = @"5555551234"` would put `@"5555551234"` in the text field, not `@"(555) 555-1234"` (which would be the result of accessing the property). In practice, the difference isn't usually apparent because getters and setters are typically just dumb accessors for ivars — but it can occasionally bite you.

Comment: Thanks, @Chuck. Edited my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Chuck, could you please write this as an answer? I would select that as "correct" one, even if both Nekto and zoul did bring up excellent points.